# "I'm told" usage and correctness

Tags: grammar, verbs

During an email exchange, I read this sentence:

> I’m told it's in hand and under control.

I searched on the net and I found that it is used to say something like "Someone told me" or "I told myself", but I thought it isn't a correct grammatical form, is it?

Is it introduced as an idiomatic form in spoken language?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*I'm told...*" in this example is somewhat idiomatic, yes.

It *does* literally mean that someone else has informed you of what follows in your statement, and could easily be read as "*I have been told that....*"; but it can also carry the implication that you are not responsible for the information if it is not correct. As such it is sometimes used as a sort of *disclaimer*.

On other occasions people say the similar "*I am reliably informed....*" which carries the same meaning that you have been told the information that follows, but goes someway to showing your confidence in the source.