# What does ’I’m told’ means as a complete sentence

Tags: idioms, idioms-in-context

I was watching MasterChef UK at https://youtu.be/8uuy_fPO2jg . If my explanation is not clear you could jump to 14.05 to find what I’m confused.

At 14.05, there’s this conversation where A is a person who cook sea trout and B mistaken her dish for a salmon.

A: Oh! Salmon! 
B: Sea trout. I’m told.

Here’s the question, what does I’m told in this context means? I understand if it’s used like “I’m told that you are a good chef” but for this conversation, I’m confused.

Thanks in advance for anyone who wish to help :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["I'm told" usage and correctness](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/174297/im-told-usage-and-correctness)

Comment: B's response is a "stylised inversion / reduction" from the more natural sequence *I'm told [that] it's sea trout.* The passive form ***I am told*** doesn't specify ***who*** told B this, but as an "active" version of what he means, you could consider ***People tell me** that this is sea trout, not salmon.*

Comment: I have upvoted FF's comment as fully correct. But he did not point out that you are obviously wrong in asserting that your example is a complete sentence consisting of only "I'm told." You are ignoring half the words in your example, which consists of a subject "I," a contraction of the passive verb "am told," and a direct object, "sea trout."  "Tell" is being used in a transitive sense in your example. What makes this tricky is that it is both an inversion and an ellipsis for "I'm told [that this fish is a] sea trout."